# With can or without can

Tags: usage

I think the following sentence is perfectly ok **without can**

> Every year this IT company conducts training programmes for employees so that they learn new skills.

But in my book it is given that **can** should be used before **learn**.

> Every year this IT company conducts training programmes for employees so that they **can** learn new skills.

Is the first sentence wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong, but conducting a training program does not ensure that the employees _will_ learn new skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with *Wehage* in the comments:

> It's not wrong, but conducting a training program does not ensure that the employees will learn new skills.

By omitting/removing the word *can*, you are implying that they will all *learn new skills*. If you include the word *can*, it implies they have the opportunity to *learn new skills* but all of them may not do so.

As you cannot garuntee they will *learn new skills*, **I would include *can***.